# ¿Como instalar librerias para python?

Tags: python

Llevo un rato intentando instalar librerias (*En este caso Colorama*) en Python con el comando.

`from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, Init`

Pero cuando corro el script en mi consola me aparece el siguiente error.

`from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init`

`ImportError: No module named colorama`

Estoy utilizando la version de python 2.7.18 y mi S.O es Kali Linux.

Comment: necesitamos más datos: cómo la instalaste, código exacto, si trabajas en virtualenv o no

Comment: dale a [edit] para añadir detalles, en los comentarios no se ve bien. También es importante explicar exactamente cómo has instalado el paquete

Comment: Saludos amigo, adjunto el código exacto: 
`from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init `
`print(Fore.RED + "Hello World") `
Instalé Colorama con el comando pip: `pip install colorama`  y no estoy desde una maquina virtual. @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'

Comment: no te dio ningún error de instalación? Desde donde estas ejecutando el código (IDE, terminal...)? Puede que lo hayas instalado en el intérprete equivocado

Comment: Hola @angogi

Yo utilizo actualmente zsh como terminal, es posible que haya tenido que configurar algo extra para poder utilizar python sin Bash?

Lo que devuelve la consola de zzh es: 

`Requirement already satisfied: colorama in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (0.4.3)
`

Comment: tienes instalado colorama en python3 pero dices que estás usando python2.7. Conclusión, tienes dos pythons instalados y te estás confundiendo en cual instalas las cosas y en cual usas los comandos. Aclara eso.

Comment: Gracias @Saelyth voy a revisar esta cuestión eliminando todas las versiones de Python y volviendo a instalar la 3

Comment: Hola @Saelyth Eliminè mi Python 2.7 y ahora teniendo disponible python 3.9 actualizado intento utilizar el comando `pip3 install colorama` y me muestra el siguiente mensaje repetidamente: `WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/colorama/`

Comment: No estoy familiarizado con Linux, pero me imagino que te falta algún modulo o algo que habilite las conexiones SSL para poder descargar modulos con ello. Otra posibilidad es que colorama no sea compatible, porque en el paquete de colorama dice que es compatible con python 3.8 pero no con 3.9.

Answer (score 1):

Las librerías no se "instalan" con el comando "import", sino que se importan para que puedan ser utilizadas en el script. La instalación de una librería es un proceso que se realiza en un terminal de comandos. Por ejemplo, para instalar colorama es necesario ejecutar la instucción:

```
pip install colorama
```

en la consola de Windows (si Python esta incluido en el PATH del sistema). pip es el instalador de paquetes de Python (si tienes la distribución Anaconda puedes utilizar el instalador `conda`). Si la instalación es correcta, podrán importar la librería y los clases/funciones en un script.

Comment: Saludos amigo, cuando yo quiero instalar Colorama utilizando `pip3 install colorama` Por que desinstale python 2 y me sale el siguiente mensaje `WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")`